# Table with spacing before/after separation line between rows

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to build a HTML table with separation line between rows.
My main concern is mainly the fact I need to add a padding left/right in my tbody.
I tried different things, such:

- Add `:before/:after` floating element to add the space
- Add `border-collapse: collapse` to the table, then add a border to the tbody, but I lost my border on the table doing that

Here is my table:

[image]

And this is what I need to do:

[image]

Codepen for the source:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gojuw

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting up a left and right border in the first and last `<td>`, respectively? See working example in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s7aSh/7/). It works something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="table_wrapper">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#table_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead td {
    background-color: #eee;
}
thead td:first-child {
    border-left: 20px solid #eee;
}
thead td:last-child {
    border-right: 20px solid #eee;
}
tbody td {
    background-color: white;
}
tbody td:first-child {
    border-left: 20px solid white;
} 
tbody td:last-child {
    border-right: 20px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i try this in my codeand it works fine it shows as you want

```
<div id="table_prove">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><td></td><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td><td></td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td></td><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td><td></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

as you can see i add a "" that separates your first item and the last from the table, you can adjust the size of your table and the td's, i hope i helped you